# HtmlUnit forbid external requests

Tags: htmlunit

I use HtmlUnit for automated tests for my site.
My site use gmaps api - and it takes a lot of time to send request for external site ( I have few hundreds of tests and few thousands of page loads).

I need some way to tell HtmlUnit to load only local pages (stored in IIS express), and forbit loading external resources to make my tests running more quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent HTMLUnit from accessing certain URL's using as `WebConnectionWrapper`:

```
browser.setWebConnection(new WebConnectionWrapper(browser) {
  @Override
  public WebResponse getResponse(final WebRequest request) throws IOException {
    if (<<CONDITION HERE(such as `request.getUrl().toString().contains("uq.edu.au")`)>>) {
      return super.getResponse(request);
    } else {
      return new StringWebResponse("", request.getUrl());
    }
  }
});
```

Unless you need to test them you may want to consider disabling items like JavaScript and CSS, I find that also speeds it up.