# How to print entire webpage contents (including dynamic contents)?

Tags: java, iframe, htmlunit

I want to read the entire webpage contents including dynamic contents (also HTML contents loaded by JavaScript inside iFrames, nested iFrames). I could simply rebuild the page with printed page contents. I tried using Java here ([How to print external script inside iframe using htmlunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631872/how-to-print-external-script-inside-iframe-using-htmlunit)) but did not succeed. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know the name of frame then use HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getWebWindowByName("Frame Name").getEnclosedPage(); and see the content of the iframe

Comment: Thanks @Kick by this way i can get the javascript, How can i get the contens(HTML) loaded by that JavaScript? is there any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the changed HTML content after it's updated by Javascript? (htmlunit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521/get-the-changed-html-content-after-its-updated-by-javascript-htmlunit)

Comment: i already checked the question what is mentioned as  **Duplicate** here `waitForBackgroundJavaScript()` doesn't work out here for my scenario, i already used `waitForBackgroundJavaScript()` no change. I dont want to wait to specific js to execute, but what i wanted is entire page contents. that is the reason why this question raised. Sorry if its duplicating.

Comment: You have to reload the page by using method currentPage.initialize();

Comment: @Kick i would like to mention here that `List<FrameWindow> fms = page2.getFrames();` `for(FrameWindow f: fms){
      System.out.println(f.getEnclosingPage().asXml());
     }`i could able to get the iframe contents (including nested iframes),without using `currentPage.initialize()`. But my main intention is to get the contents as it is. Is there any way?